# Templating a double-templated class method

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-templates

This is my simplified code :

```
template<typename device, template<typename device> class protocol>
class MyClass
{
public:
  template<typename select>
  bool method()
  {
    // Code
  }
};
```

I want `method` to act different in terms of the `protocol` type.

In other words, I have two different possible protocols, and I want to have two different behaviours for my method according to the protocols. But I don't know how to write it with templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By example, using SFINAE (if you accept a C++11 solution)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename>
struct protocol_1
 { };

template <typename>
struct protocol_2
 { };

template<typename device, template<typename> class protocol>
class MyClass
 {
   public:
      template<typename select, typename p = protocol<device>>
         typename std::enable_if<
         std::is_same<p, protocol_1<device>>::value, bool>::type
         method()
       { return true; }

      template<typename select, typename p = protocol<device>>
         typename std::enable_if<
         std::is_same<p, protocol_2<device>>::value, bool>::type
         method()
       { return false; }
 };

int main()
 {
   MyClass<int, protocol_1>  m1;
   MyClass<int, protocol_2>  m2;

   std::cout << m1.method<int>() << std::endl; // print 1 (true)
   std::cout << m2.method<void>() << std::endl; // print 0 (false)
 }
```

**--- EDIT ---**

As pointed by Yakk (thanks!), this solution is weak because use a template default value that can be explicited and circunvented.

An example; with

```
MyClass<int, protocol_1>{}.method<void>();
```

is called the "protocol_1" version of `method()`, using the default value for `p`; but explciting `p`, as follows

```
MyClass<int, protocol_1>{}.method<void, protocol_2<int>>();
```

is called the "protocol_2" version of `method()` over an istance of a `MyClass` based on `protocol_1`

To avoid this problem it's possible add a `static_assert()`, in both version of `method()`, to check and impose that `p` is equal to its default value (`protocol<device>`)

I mean... as follow

```
  template<typename select, typename p = protocol<device>>
     typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<p, protocol_1<device>>::value, bool>::type
     method()
   {
     static_assert(std::is_same<p, protocol<device>>::value, "!");

     return true;
   }

  template<typename select, typename p = protocol<device>>
     typename std::enable_if<
     std::is_same<p, protocol_2<device>>::value, bool>::type
     method()
   {
     static_assert(std::is_same<p, protocol<device>>::value, "!");

     return false;
   }
```

So

```
MyClass<int, protocol_1>{}.method<void, protocol_2<int>>();
```

generate a compiler error.

Comment: Note that this approach is very fragile, for if the bodies are only valid under the assumption nobody passes template argument 2, you get an ill formed program no diagnostic required.  What worse is no compiler will diagnose the problem; your code will appear to work perfectly.

Comment: @skyp search for "no diagnostic required", there are only a dozen or so in the standard.  The one about templates must have valid specializations (which means something different in the standard than colloquially)

Comment: @Yakk Got it. Thank you.

Comment: @Yakk - you're right; thanks. Answer improved adding a `static_assert()` based check. What do you think of it?

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment.
This is not really what I needed, I need the behaviours to be different like that :
Server<UnixSock, TCPIO>::Select<UnixSelect> == Server<WinSock, TCPIO>::Select<WinSelect>
Server<UnixSock, UDPIO>::Select<UnixSelect> == Server<WinSock, UDPIO>::Select<WinSelect>
The behaviour changes with the second parameter of the main class template

Comment: The static assert just makes it more clear your code is ill formed.  It does not fix it.  The problem is that the standard mandates that all template functions must have a valid instantiation possible.  Your trick makes an ill formed program under the standard that usually (basically always in current compilers) compiles and behaves the way you intend; the program remains ill formed.  Next weeks compiler update could cause arbitrary breakage.

Comment: @Yakk - Sorry: I didn't understand; do you refer to 14.6.8: "If no valid specialization can be generated for a template definition, and that template is not instantiated, the template definition is ill-formed, no diagnostic required."? So the solution, to avoid the ill formed problem, is to add a third `method()` that is enabled only if `p` is different from `protocol_1<device>` and from `protocol_2<device>`?

Comment: @max your templates are overloads of each other, not specializations.  In short, each must have a valid set of possible template arguments that make it a valid function.  This fundamentally is opposed to your technique.  There are ways to make it work,  but it is fragile.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention which is the target standard, so I'll try to give you an alternative for all the seasons.

---

In C++11/14 you can use tag dispatching and function overloading to do that.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename> struct protocol_a {};
template<typename> struct protocol_b {};

template<typename device, template<typename> class protocol>
class MyClass {
    template<template<typename> class> struct tag {};

    template<typename select>
    bool method(tag<protocol_a>) {
        std::cout << "protocol_a" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }

    template<typename select>
    bool method(tag<protocol_b>) {
        std::cout << "protocol_b" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

public:
    template<typename select>
    bool method() {
        return method<device>(tag<protocol>{});
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass<int, protocol_a> mca;
    mca.method<void>();
    MyClass<int, protocol_b> mcb;
    mcb.method<void>();
}
```

Pretty compact. It doesn't require extra classes, partial specializations or sfinae expressions. The *drawback* (if we can call this *a drawback*) is that you have one more level of indirection.

---

In C++17 you can use `if constexpr` to get the same result.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>

template<typename> struct protocol_a {};
template<typename> struct protocol_b {};

template<typename device, template<typename> class protocol>
class MyClass {
public:
    template<typename select>
    bool method() {
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<protocol<device>, protocol_a<device>>) {
            std::cout << "protocol_a" << std::endl;
            return true;
        } else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<protocol<device>, protocol_b<device>>) {
            std::cout << "protocol_b" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass<int, protocol_a> mca;
    mca.method<void>();
    MyClass<int, protocol_b> mcb;
    mcb.method<void>();
}
```

More compact, but C++17 could not be an option.
See it running on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wujh0fgF4e8JORMH).

Answer (score 1):

Use an external helper is another possible solution:

```
template <typename T>
struct B {
};
template <template<typename> class protocol, typename select>
struct helper {
    static bool do_real() {
        return true;
    }
};
template <typename select>
struct helper<B, select> {
    static bool do_real() {
        return false;
    }
};
template<typename device, template<typename> class protocol>
class MyClass
{
public:
  template<typename select>
  bool method()
  {
    return helper<protocol, select>::do_real();
  }
};
```

Like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wrzBfJDEySwxkGeC)

Answer (score 0):

You may partial specialize the class, something like:

```
template<typename device, template<typename> class protocol>
class MyClass;

template <typename> struct protocole1 { /* ... */ };
template <typename> struct protocole2 { /* ... */ };

template<typename device>
class MyClass<device, protocol1>
{
public:
  template<typename select>
  bool method()
  {
    // Code for protocole1
  }
};

template<typename device>
class MyClass<device, protocol2>
{
public:
  template<typename select>
  bool method()
  {
    // Code for protocole2
  }
};
```